# Apply strike out text on row

Tags: conditional-formatting, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a question about Excel 2007 and I'm not sure if its even possible, but if any community can help it's here.

I want to strike out all the text for all cells in a row if the text in column A for that row is a certain value, in my case "inactive."

And I would like to have this done on multiple sheet and multiple workbooks, so a portable and easy solution would be best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditional Formatting is a tricky beast in Excel and what you are looking to do requires that you use a logical formula to get this done. Here is what I do to get this to work:

- Open "Manage Rules" under conditional formatting.
- Create a New rule using "a formula to determine which cells to format.
- Use the following formula and modify it to match your data columns.

> =OR($B1="Inactive")

- Setup the formatting and create the rule.
- Once You have the rule, change the "Applies to" to match the following. The letters should match the left and right most column you want affected.

> =$A:$B

- Once you change the affected range, edit the rule and check to see if the cell reference changed. It will sometimes switch the row number to some large number. Change it back to 1 if it changed.

That should do it. You can use AND depending on how many conditions you want the row to match. Just make sure that you always use the first row as your reference.

Hope this helps

Comment: Or just use =$A1="inactive"

Comment: @Tog - I like using OR/AND since it scales from 1 condition to many conditions. Though for something quick, your equation is simpler.

Comment: @Tog @Doltknuckle - Thank you both for the answers, I was having problems with the conditional copying, but Dolt's answer using the affected option works beautifully. Thank you both again!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the conditional formatting tool
Home > Styles > Conditional Formatting
Select "New Rule" then highlight "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
Click in the "Edit the rule description" box
Click in the cell which will contain your "inactive" text which will put the cell address into the box. You will need to remove the dollar sign from in front of the number part of the cell reference to allow each row to reference the correct cell in the column that contains your "inactive" text
Click on "Format"  and select the "Stirikethrough box until it displays a tick

Comment: I looked at that but I don't know a way I could use that to affect a whole row based on the value in column A. Could you please be a little more specific?

Comment: Forgot to add, you can conditional paste the format into other cells